# Spring Boot with MyBatis - @MapperScan error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to set up Spring Boot with MyBatis.  When I try and launch my application, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan.factoryBean()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)     
    at ...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at com.mydomain.Server.launch(Server.java:70)
    at com.mydomain.Server.main(Server.java:93)
```

I'm using the following versions in my `pom.xml` in order to get things set up:

- spring-boot-dependencies @ 1.5.9.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-dependencies @ Edgware.SR1
- mybatis @ 3.4.5
- mybatis-spring @ 1.3.1

I also have the following included:

- mybatis-spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-configuration-processor
- spring-cloud-config-client
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- spring-boot-starter

I'm not sure if there is a conflict or what, but it's not letting me set up my mappers.  Any suggestions are happily welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so the problem is a conflict between **mybatis @ 3.4.5** and **mybatis-spring @ 1.3.1**.

When I dropped *mybatis @ 3.4.5* everything worked just fine.

Comment: ANy further hints? I am getting the same error with current versions of Mybatis (3.4.6) and Mybatis-Spring (1.3.2)

Comment: Yes - you need to basically massage the versions.  It's dependency hell in Spring, mostly.  I had to step through the source in the IDE to figure out what was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I tried **mybatis-spring-boot**:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.spring.boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter/1.3.2 
My application is running ok.

I hope it helps you.